# Подключение JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, gradle, jstl

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

В build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.web', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api', version: '1.2.1'
providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
```

Запускаю сервер -

> The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

В чём беда? Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я помню, по умолчанию Tomcat не укомплектован JSTL. Либо скачайте jstl-1.2.jar и положите в lib сервера, либо замените `providedCompile` на `compile` в конфигурации сборки вашего приложения.